# Catalog Search is struck in reindexing

Tags: catalog, search

Catalog search is strucked while reindexing. It's taking too much time.

Comment: We need more information - server type? Server memory? Where is Elastic hosted?

Comment: I used this command to fasten the reindex process:   php bin/magento ind:res
MAGE_INDEXER_THREADS_COUNT=3 php -f bin/magento indexer:reindex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the batch size can help you optimize indexer running time :
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/indexer-optimization.html

Answer (score 0):

I used this command to fasten the reindex process:
php bin/magento ind:res MAGE_INDEXER_THREADS_COUNT=3 php -f bin/magento indexer:reindex